# Difficulty with poly2nb() and nb2mat() in spdep package

Tags: r, spdep

I would appreciate some advice on making a spatial weights matrix using the spdep() package.

(1) If I have spatial data download from the `rnaturalearth` package, and a list of countries in another dataset, what is an efficient way to subset the data. To be specific I have:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
ne_sf <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")
```

And I have a list of countries so that `dput(in_data_set)` returns:

```
c("ALB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BEL", "BGD", 
"BGR", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BOL", "BRA", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", 
"CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "CMR", "COD", "COG", "COL", "CRI", "CYP", 
"DEU", "DJI", "DNK", "DZA", "ECU", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", 
"FIN", "FJI", "FRA", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GNB", "GNQ", "GRC", 
"GUY", "HRV", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", 
"JAM", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KHM", "KWT", "LBN", "LBR", 
"LBY", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAR", "MDG", "MEX", 
"MLI", "MNE", "MNG", "MOZ", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", "NIC", "NLD", 
"NOR", "NPL", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "POL", 
"PRT", "QAT", "ROU", "SAU", "SEN", "SLE", "SLV", "SRB", "SVN", 
"SWE", "TCD", "THA", "TJK", "TTO", "TUN", "UKR", "URY", "USA", 
"VNM", "ZAF", "ZMB")
```

So the question is how could I use this vector of three letter country codes to subset the data. one of the objects in `ne_sf` is `iso_a3` against which the country codes could be matched.

2. When I skip ahead and try to create a (non-subsetted) spatial matrix I get an error as follows (which I assume will not disappear when I subset the data):

   w_ne_sf  <- poly2nb(ne_sf) %>% nb2mat(style = "W")

   > Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  :
   > Loop 7 is not valid: Edge 172 crosses edge 174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the first problem is easy:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
ne_sf <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")

incl <- c("ALB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BEL", "BGD", 
          "BGR", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BOL", "BRA", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", 
          "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", "CMR", "COD", "COG", "COL", "CRI", "CYP", 
          "DEU", "DJI", "DNK", "DZA", "ECU", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", 
          "FIN", "FJI", "FRA", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GNB", "GNQ", "GRC", 
          "GUY", "HRV", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "ISL", "ISR", "ITA", 
          "JAM", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KHM", "KWT", "LBN", "LBR", 
          "LBY", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAR", "MDG", "MEX", 
          "MLI", "MNE", "MNG", "MOZ", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", "NIC", "NLD", 
          "NOR", "NPL", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "POL", 
          "PRT", "QAT", "ROU", "SAU", "SEN", "SLE", "SLV", "SRB", "SVN", 
          "SWE", "TCD", "THA", "TJK", "TTO", "TUN", "UKR", "URY", "USA", 
          "VNM", "ZAF", "ZMB")

ne_sub <- ne_sf %>% 
  filter(iso_a3 %in% incl)
nrow(ne_sf)
#> [1] 177
nrow(ne_sub)
#> [1] 111
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The answer to the second is more challenging. [This](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/1902) GitHub issue suggests that the spherical geometry may not work well here and that you could rebuild it if that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, taking DaveArmstrong's hint I was able to get over the line. I was able to sort the effort with the following:

```
ne_sub1 <- st_make_valid(ne_sub)
w_ne_sub  <- poly2nb(ne_sub1) %>% nb2mat(style = "W", zero.policy=TRUE)
```

Thanks all